# how to make different ranges by using a variable in python?

Tags: python

I want to know is there any simple way to make ranges instead of the below code (buckets =np.where........).If there is any simple way to do that please help me how can i do that.In the below code textdata is my maindata and userid and smstext are my variables

taking subset from textdata

```
userfreq = textdata[['userid', 'smstext']]
```

calcuating the count by userid

```
user_freq = userfreq.groupby('userid').agg(len)
```

resetting the index

```
 user_freq.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

subsetting sms text to make the buckets

```
tobebuckets = user_freq['smstext'] #here smstext is nothing but the frequencies of users
```

Making different ranges

```
buckets = np.where(
tobebuckets <= 0, 0,
np.where(
    np.logical_and(tobebuckets > 0, tobebuckets <= 10), 10,
    np.where(
        np.logical_and(tobebuckets > 10,tobebuckets <= 50), 50,
        np.where(
            np.logical_and(tobebuckets > 50, tobebuckets <= 100), 100,
            np.where(
                np.logical_and(tobebuckets > 100, tobebuckets <= 500), 500,
                np.where(
                    np.logical_and(tobebuckets > 500, tobebuckets <= 1000),
                    1000, 1001))))))
```

Thanks in advance.please tell me the simple way to do the above in python

Comment: Wouldn't `numpy.histogram` do the trick? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html ?

Comment: i saw that but can i know how can i write the code for above using numpy.histogram

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `digitize`:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(1500) - 5
top = 1 + x.max()
bins = np.array([0,10,50,100,500,1000,top])
result = bins[np.digitize(x,bins)]
#if you really want 1001 at the top
result = np.where(result==top,1001,result) #or just clip it
```